# How to skip inside a python for loo

Tags: python

Is there any way to skip significant amount of iterations within a for loop ,for example if I have a for loop from 1 million to 100 million, if the first digit starts with 2 ,4 ,6 ,8 , I would like to skip the whole 2 million to 3 million.Then, when I get to 10 million ,the same thing but this time, skip the range 20 million to 30 million.The ranges that I would like to skip within my range are from the ones that start with the digit 2, to the one that starts with the digit 3, digit 4 to digit 7 and digit 8 to digit 9. Is it possible and if yes, how?

Comment: Please edit your code to a readable format.

Comment: Why does it need to be a for loop? What does "doesn't start" mean?

Comment: Why not use a while loop?

Comment: Your code, as shown, makes no sense. Even if reformatted, it's invalid

Comment: ''range'' is not the droid loop you're looking for! :)

Comment: Sorry guys, new to Stack Overflow. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You might use `filter` to select elements which you want to process, you need to deliver function to it which, which given element return `True` if element is to be processed else `False`, consider following simple example

```
def start_with_1_3_5(number):
    return str(number).startswith(("1", "3", "5"))


for i in filter(start_with_1_3_5, range(99)):
    print(i)
```

gives output

```
1
3
5
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
```